# Passing JSON data to POST in Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I have developed rest API using spring MVC. My controller class has the following rest method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/students", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createStudents(@RequestBody Student student) {

     System.out.println(student.getStudentSkillSet().toString());
    // System.out.println(student.getStudentDob().toString());

    final String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO test(studentName,studentCourse,studentSkillSet,studentDob)" + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

    Object[] params = new Object[] { student.getStudentName(), student.getStudentCourse(),
            student.getStudentSkillSet(),student.getStudentDob() };

    // define SQL types of the arguments
    int[] types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,Types.DATE };

    jdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, params, types);

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

How I passed data to this method using Postman tool in the body tab in POSTMAN:

```json
{
    "student_name": {"test"},
    "studentCourse": {"computer"},
    "studentSkillSet": {["springmvc","springboot"]}
    "studentDob":2020/09/12
}
```

But when i run this i got error like the following

```
22:15:13,142 INFO[stdout(defaulttask1)org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
22:15:13,142 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.demo.model.Student["student_name"]) occures 
22:15:13,143 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-1) Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.demo.model.Student["student_name"])] to ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'Exception'; model is {}
```

### My student class

```
package com.demo.model;
```

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class Student {

```
private String studentName;
private String studentCourse;
private Date studentDob;
private List<String> studentSkillSet;
private Address studentAddress;


public Date getStudentDob() {
    return studentDob;
}
public void setStudentDob(Date studentDob) {
    this.studentDob = studentDob;
}

public Address getStudentAddress() {
    return studentAddress;
}
public void setStudentAddress(Address studentAddress) {
    this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
}
public List<String> getStudentSkillSet() {
    return studentSkillSet;
}
public void setStudentSkillSet(List<String> studentSkillSet) {
    this.studentSkillSet = studentSkillSet;
}
public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}
public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}
public String getStudentCourse() {
    return studentCourse;
}
public void setStudentCourse(String studentCourse) {
    this.studentCourse = studentCourse;
}
```

}

### Address Class

```
public class Address {


public Address(String addressLine1, int pinCode, String state) {
    super();
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    this.pinCode = pinCode;
    this.state = state;
}

private String addressLine1;
private String addressLine2;
private String city;
private int pinCode;
private String state;

public String getaddressLine1() {
    return addressLine1;
}

public void setaddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
}

public String getaddressLine2() {
    return addressLine2;
}

public void setaddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
    this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public int getPinCode() {
    return pinCode;
}

public void setPinCode(int pinCode) {
    this.pinCode = pinCode;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
```

}

Comment: Please share the `Student` class

Comment: We need your Student class, since Jackson can not de serialize it. In any case Spring MVC is not the best idea for REST, check Spring Web Flux.

Comment: `{"test"}` is not valid JSON, so I recommend you **learn more about JSON**, before you try to work any further with it.

Comment: `{
 "student_name": "test",
 "studentCourse": "computer",
 "studentSkillSet": ["springmvc","springboot"]
 "studentDob":2020/09/12
} `  Is this a valid json

Comment: Please also share the `Address` class

Comment: shared the Address class. But my problem is with the variable studentSkill set .I passesd in jason like this ` "studentSkillSet": ["springmvc","springboot"],` but its not working :(

Comment: I made the necessary change but I got exception like this `[stdout] (default task-1) org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO test(studentName,studentCourse,studentSkillSet,studentDob)VALUES (?,?,?,?)Parameter index out of range (5 > number of parameters, which is 4).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (5 > number of parameters, which is 4). occures `

Comment: This is a different problem. Please open a new question and accept an answer here.

Comment: In the future, I would recommend trying to dissect the problem. What things do you know are working? Where could the problem lie? Could you reduce your example and thereby isolate the code? Try to make assumptions, hard code things you know are working, etc. This will allow you to narrow down the problem and then search for existing questions that precisely match your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess what your `Student` class looks like, but most likely you don't need the curly braces around the name etc:

```json
{
    "student_name": "test",
    "studentCourse": "computer",
    "studentSkillSet": ["springmvc","springboot"],
    "studentDob": "2020-09-12"
}
```

Comment: `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String "2020/09/12": not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2020/09/12': Cannot parse date "2020/09/12": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))`   Getting this excetion!!! how to give a date value through json?

Comment: Please suggest a youtube video or a doc which explains who to connect MySQL with Spring MVC  I'm getting stuck for past two days :(

Comment: Change as below -private Date studentDob; -> private String studentDob;

Comment: I have updated the date, but the Address will still be missing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @rethab , with the solution, and yes , if will get the exception is also correct, as  field studentDob will have to change to String as the json we passed likewise.

```
  private Date studentDob; -> private String studentDob;
```

Now in your controller you will get the student object but you will have to change studentDob from String to Date as below -

```
Date date =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(student.getStudentDob());  



{
    "student_name": "test",
    "studentCourse": "computer",
    "studentSkillSet": ["springmvc","springboot"],
    "studentDob": "2020/09/12"
}
```